# onClick() doesn't work to target elements in dropkick.js

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm using the super awesome dropkick.js, but i'm noticing one small thing; targeting the elements within it's lists doesn't seem possible with jquery onClick() event.

I've tried using nth child selectors (which work great via css) and alerts and stop propigation and all sorts of different methods; but for some reason, whenever I click an eleement in the list, it doesn't hear that I've clicked that element and doesn't proceed to do what I'm asking it to. Here's my code:

```
<div class="dk_options" style="top: 34px;">
     <ul class="dk_options_inner">
          <li class="" style=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="">PICK A PRINT</a></li>
          <li class="digital dk_option_current" style=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="digital">Giclee Print</a></li>
          <li class="screen"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="screen">Screen Print</a></li>
     </ul>    
</div>
```

And here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.screen-price').hide();

  $('.screen').click(function(){
      $('.digital-price').hide();
      $('.screen-price').show();
      return false;
   });

   $('.digital').click(function(){
      $('.screen-price').hide();
      $('.digital-price').show();
      return false;
   });

   $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
      return false;
   });              

    });


</script>
```

I'm not sure what the deal is; I've tried all sorts of solutions. Please let me know.

Comment: The only classes I see in your markup are `dk_options, dk_options_inner, digital, dk_option_current, screen` and your jQuery selectors are using a bunch with dashes (`-`) in them. Is that mismatch the source of your difficulty?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply!

I should have mentioned that the jquery is targeting some H2's I have: 

<h2 class="digital-price">Some Price</h2>
<h2 class="screen-price">Some Price</h2>

So the way it's working is I'm telling it to hide the screen price, and onClick .screen in the drop-down menu, to swap the h2's via hide/show.

So, I think it's targeting the right elements, but I'm not sure why it's not firing off. Could this have something to do with event bubbling?

Comment: In my local test of what you've got it all appears to work correctly. The first step would be to put `alert` or `console.log` calls in each of the event handlers and determine whether they are being hit or not for you.

Comment: I tried that too; but for some reason it's still not firing off. I'm also checking it out in my console but nothing is show up. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think I've figured this out. I'm not sure why it's working like this, but it is.

So, in order to target my menus, I have to:

1) Call the menu specifically; in this case it's .price-menu

2) Make sure I call it using .dropkick

```
$('.price-menu').dropkick({
```

3) Use a `change: function()` statement

4) String it all together to look something like this:

```
$('.price-menu').dropkick({
  change: function () {
      $('.screen').click(function(){
  })}
});
```

Now, for some reason, the code that does what I want it to do is outside of this whole thing, but still within the scrip itsefl; check it out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.screen-price').hide();

$('.price-menu').dropkick({
  change: function () {
      $('.screen').click(function(){
  })}
});

$('.screen').click(function(){
      $('.digital-price').hide();
      $('.screen-price').show();
});

$('.digital').click(function(){
      $('.screen-price').hide();
      $('.digital-price').show();
});
```

});

That does the trick. I'm not sure why exactly, but it works.

Anyone have any insight on how this works or would care to explain it to me?

Also, thank you so much to everyone who's posted to this thread - I appreciate it :c)

Cheers!
JC