# Assign a Click function to a select element styled with Dropkick jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, onclick

How can I assign a 'click' function to a `<select>` element styled with the [Dropkick jQuery plugin](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/)? Dropkick doesn't directly support `click` functions so I'm trying to create a separate 'click' function, but the method I've tried doesn't work

```
$('#Select1').click(function () {
    var $select2 = $('#Select2');
    removeDefaultFromSelect($select2);
});
```

I know that change event handlers must be assigned with the plugin's 'custom `change` callback', but I'm assuming that there is a way to call a `click` function on an element styled with Dropkick *(especially because [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508128/1056713) seems to suggest that there is way to call it within Dropkick's 'custom `change` callback')*.

I'm trying to add a click function so that the function below can be triggered when '#Select1' is clicked, and not just when it's changed. I've posted a working example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/zJ5c3/#username

*Existing Function*

```
// Helper function that removes "_default" from the end of the option values for the given select element.
function removeDefaultFromSelect($select) {
    $select.find('option[value$=_default]').prop('value', function(i, value){ return value.replace(/_default$/g, '');
    });
}

$('#Select1').dropkick({
    change: function(value) {     
        var $select2 = $('#Select2');
        removeDefaultFromSelect($select2);
        $select2.val(value);      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to use the `click` event with Dropkick, but I've figured out a somewhat complicated temporary workaround by creating 2 sets of `<select>` elements - one set uses standard elements and is hidden *(`display:none`)*, and another set that uses Dropkick and is visible to the user. Because it uses the `change()` method the value isn't modified if the user clicks on the dropdown box and then consciously decides to leave the 'default' value.

I've posted a fiddle with the method I used here: http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/yhAX5/4/.

```
function removeDefaultFromSelect($select) {
    $select.find('option[value$=_default]').prop('value', function(i, value){ return value.replace(/_default$/g, '');
    });
}

$('#Select1').dropkick({
    change: function(value) {
        var $select2 = $('#Select2');
        removeDefaultFromSelect($select2);
        $select2.val(value);
    }
});
```